# How to change macOS keyboard shortcuts so I don’t need to press the function key in combo with F4 to bring up launchpad?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

On my old MacBook Air 2012, <kbd>F4</kbd> brings up Launchpad without pressing the <kbd>fn</kbd> key.

On MacBook Air M2, <kbd>F4</kbd> brings up Spotlight, which I've already accustomed to bring up by using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. I had to press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to get the actual <kbd>F4</kbd> to bring up the Launchpad.

Is there anyway I could remap it to make it go to Launchpad instead of Spotlight? I don't even know what this feature is called because going to settings to change keyboard shortcut it doesn't seem like it can be remapped.

Comment: What OS was installed on the 2012 MacBook Air? This all seems like a macOS issue rather than a 2012 MacBook Air versus an MacBook Air S2 issue.

Comment: It is Mojave. I think it's a machine issue though because the shortcut is drawn on the functions key themselves. Anyhow, I like the old way better and I'm looking to remap that key if possible.

Comment: Ahhh… Makes sense… I transitioned from a MacBook Air (Intel; 2020) to a MacBook Air (M2; 2022) and notice similar behavior. But it doesn’t impede my daily work so haven’t had investigate it. Might do that for this question.

Comment: With many Windows computers, the F keys have given way to special keys and you have to press Fn to get the F function, but there's also usually a setting in the BIOS to switch this based on preference. Does Mac OS have such a switch setting? I don't know, but I would guess that it does not.

Comment: What you're describing about the F keys and Fn keys work the same way on a Mac. To change this behavior so that you're getting the F keys without using Fn is a matter of making changes inside Settings (the equivalent of of the Windows Control Panel), however that'll make all other special keys less convenient for me so I don't want that either.